# How to iterate through child elements of a div selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to scrap a java based website for the table. However the Table data are separated in all different tables. I need to scrap the names and Roles off this table.

I unfortunately cannot give the URL out as its an internal website but I have attached the html code, Names have also been changed for security reasons

This is the website code:

```
<div role="presentation" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
   <div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="admin" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">admin</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="locked">
                     <div class="sprite warning13 mar5r"></div>
                     Locked
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell" idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">08/07/13 07:17:49 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user1" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user1</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="connected">
                     <div class="sprite checkMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Connected (2)
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">07/04/22 03:37:32 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user2" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user2</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">06/27/22 09:55:30 AM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user3" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user3</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">12/18/19 03:56:05 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user4" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user4</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">05/20/22 05:49:45 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user5" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user5</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">05/19/22 12:16:31 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user6" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user6</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">07/01/22 03:24:16 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="secadmin" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">secadmin</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="locked">
                     <div class="sprite warning13 mar5r"></div>
                     Locked
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="security_admin">Security administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">06/07/21 03:28:40 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="tpcuser" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">tpcuser</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="monitor">Monitor</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">PUBLIC</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">03/03/21 06:00:33 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="dojoxGridRow dojoxGridRowOdd" role="row" aria-selected="false" idref="user6" style="">
      <table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="name">user6</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:12em;" hilite="1" fieldname="state">
                  <div class="stateCouple userState" data-state="disconnected">
                     <div class="sprite disabledMark13 mar5r"></div>
                     Disconnected
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style="width:14em;" hilite="1" fieldname="role"><span class="hasMapTooltip" tooltipkey="admin">Administrator</span></td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="3" style="display:none;width:10em;" hilite="1" fieldname="scope">*</td>
               <td tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="4" style="display:none;width:16em;" hilite="1" fieldname="lastAuthenticatedTime">05/10/22 12:39:54 PM</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

There is a possibility for future additions to users so I cannot have a set number for the loop.

My code is the following:

```
#Scrape the user table 
Username = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
Role = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]")  

for i in range(len(Username)):

    if Username[i].text in userdict:
        UserGet = userdict.get(Username[i].text)
        print("Company Name|F|DS0000|Company Role|" + UserGet + "|enabled|||" + Role[i].text)
        List.append("Company Name|F|DS0000|Company Role|" + UserGet + "|enabled|||" + Role[i].text)
            

    else: 
        print(Username[i].text + " Not in User Dictionary")
```

I hope my question makes sense and appreciate any help provided

Edit:

Name 1 = /html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]

Name 2 = /html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]

Somehow I need to loop through the divs but have and end point

Comment: Its better to use clasname, Id, attribute name or tagname, please do not chain the divs as it makes the code really hard to read

Comment: I would generally however i feel i need to use the divs in this to achieve what I want

Answer (score 0):

If you correct the XPath values it should give you the expected result. I tested it using this website http://xpather.com/ but I'm not so great with dictionaries in Python so I could not properly test the code. Let me know if there are any issues and I can try to resolve them.

```
#Scrape the user table 
Username = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value="//td[@role][1]")
Role = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value="//td/span[@tooltipkey]")  

for i in range(len(Username)):

    if Username[i].text in userdict:
        UserGet = userdict.get(Username[i].text)
        print("Company Name|F|DS0000|Company Role|" + UserGet + "|enabled|||" + Role[i].text)
        List.append("Company Name|F|DS0000|Company Role|" + UserGet + "|enabled|||" + Role[i].text)
            

    else: 
        print(Username[i].text + " Not in User Dictionary")
```

Comment: If you look into the edit i just made on the question, I have to loop through the divs but unsure how to tell it how many times to loop because the length of the list will change

Comment: The modified XPath values give the name and the role of every single user since it's in a for loop dictated by how many users there are in the HTML code. Do you need it to be at a specific number so for example only get the first 5 users?

As long as the format stays the same in the sense that every user will be in a table and have a role assigned then it should continue to work. If you are adding on or removing users but not making any structural changes to the HTML it won't affect the usability of the code.